# Automating ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have some arbitrary number of servers with the same user/pass combination.  I want to write a script (that I call once) so that

`ssh-copy-id user@myserver`

is called for each server.  Since they all have the same user/pass this should be easy but `ssh-copy-id` wants me to type the password in separately each time which defeats the purpose of my script. There is no option for putting in a password, ie `ssh-copy-id -p mypassword user@myserver`.

How can I write a script that automatically fills in the password field when `ssh-copy-id` asks for it?

Comment: why do you use user/pass identification instead of user/publickey identification?

Comment: because I'm using this script to set up the user/publickey.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Take a look at [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/). Place your password in a text file and do something like this:

```
$ sshpass -f password.txt ssh-copy-id user@yourserver
```

Comment: its not working on Centos7 just run without error and no key on remote server

Comment: if you get silent fail it is probably checking for known hosts - if you just try and ssh to the host you might tsee the prompt to accept unknown host and add to known hosts. You can add the -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no option as arg for the ssh-copy-id command to make this work.

Answer (score 26):

You can use expect to listen for the password prompt and send your password:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh-copy-id $argv
expect "password:"
send "YOUR_PASSWORD\n"
expect eof
```

Save the script, make it executable, and call it like: `./login.expect user@myserver`

Comment: Do you need a newer version of bash to use `spawn`?  For reasons I can't control I'm stuck with bash v3.2.

Comment: Bash version shouldn't matter. I tested with expect 5.44.1.15, but I've used similar with older versions of expect. Are you having trouble using the script?

Comment: `spawn: command not found`

Comment: `spawn` is an expect keyword (see expect(1) manual). Sounds like the script is being interpreted as shell rather than expect. Do you have expect installed? What happens if you run expect directly: `expect -f login.expect user@myserver`

Comment: The only problem is `The authenticity of host can't be established. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` for new servers.

Comment: @Envek I was just going to add this but it's nice to see that the last comment is a direct question for the thing that I was going to write. Use this line instead: `spawn ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $argv`

Comment: before password it ask for yes/no for fingerprints, how we can handle that

Comment: 1) Don't forget `ssh-keygen` if you get `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found` 2) `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` 3) `timeout 2` if you have some servers that are bad

Answer (score 6):

quanta's answer is pretty good, but it requires you to put your password in a text file.

From the `sshpass` man page:

> If no option is given, sshpass reads the password from the standard
> input.

So, what you can do is to capture the password once during the script, store it in a variable, echo the password and pipe that to sshpass as an input.

I do this all the time and it works fine. Example:

```
echo "Please insert the password used for ssh login on remote machine:"
read -r USERPASS
for TARGETIP in $@; do
  echo "$USERPASS" | sshpass ssh-copy-id -f -i $KEYLOCATION "$USER"@"$TARGETIP"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than type your password multiple times you can make use of `pssh` and its `-A` switch to prompt for it once, and then feed the password to all the servers in a list.

**NOTE:** Using this method doesn't allow you to use `ssh-copy-id`, however, so you'll need to roll your own method for appending your SSH pub key file to your remote account's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

#### Example

Here's an example that does the job:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/my_id_rsa.pub                    \
    | pssh -h ips.txt -l remoteuser -A -I -i  \
    '                                         \
      umask 077;                              \
      mkdir -p ~/.ssh;                        \
      afile=~/.ssh/authorized_keys;           \
      cat - >> $afile;                        \
      sort -u $afile -o $afile                \
    '
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password:
[1] 23:03:58 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.1
[2] 23:03:58 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.2
[3] 23:03:58 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.3
[4] 23:03:58 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.10
[5] 23:03:58 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.5
[6] 23:03:58 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.6
[7] 23:03:58 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.9
[8] 23:03:59 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.8
[9] 23:03:59 [SUCCESS] 10.252.1.7
```

The above script is generally structured like so:

```
$ cat <pubkey> | pssh -h <ip file> -l <remote user> -A -I -i '...cmds to add pubkey...'
```

#### High level `pssh` details

- `cat <pubkey>` outputs the public key file to `pssh`
- `pssh` uses the `-I` switch to ingest data via STDIN
- `-l <remote user>` is the remote server's account (we're assuming you have the same username across the servers in the IP file)
- `-A` tells `pssh` to ask for your password and then reuse it for all the servers that it connects to
- `-i` tells `pssh` to send any output to STDOUT rather than store it in files (its default behavior)
- `'...cmds to add pubkey...'` - this is the trickiest part of what's going on, so I'll break this down by itself *(see below)*

#### Commands being run on remote servers

These are the commands that `pssh` will run on each server:

```
'                                         \
  umask 077;                              \
  mkdir -p ~/.ssh;                        \
  afile=~/.ssh/authorized_keys;           \
  cat - >> $afile;                        \
  sort -u $afile -o $afile                \
'
```

##### **In order:**

- set the remote user's umask to 077, this is so that any directories or files we're going to create, will have their permissions set accordingly like so:

  ```
    $ ls -ld ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
    drwx------ 2 remoteuser remoteuser 4096 May 21 22:58 /home/remoteuser/.ssh
    -rw------- 1 remoteuser remoteuser  771 May 21 23:03 /home/remoteuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```
- create the directory `~/.ssh` and ignore warning us if it's already there
- set a variable, `$afile`, with the path to authorized_keys file
- `cat - >> $afile` - take input from STDIN and append to authorized_keys file
- `sort -u $afile -o $afile` - uniquely sorts authorized_keys file and saves it

**NOTE:** That last bit is to handle the case where you run the above multiple times against the same servers. This will eliminate your pubkey from getting appended multiple times.

#### Notice the single ticks!

Also pay special attention to the fact that all these commands are nested inside of single quotes. That's important, since we don't want `$afile` to get evaluated until after it's executing on the remote server.

```
'               \
   ..cmds...    \
'
```

I've expanded the above so it's easier to read here, but I generally run it all on a single line like so:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/my_id_rsa.pub | pssh -h ips.txt -l remoteuser -A -I -i 'umask 077; mkdir -p ~/.ssh; afile=~/.ssh/authorized_keys; cat - >> $afile; sort -u $afile -o $afile'
```

#### Bonus material

By using `pssh` you can forgo having to construct files and either provide dynamic content using `-h <(...some command...)` or you can create a list of IPs using another of `pssh`'s switches, `-H "ip1 ip2 ip3"`.

For example:

```
$ cat .... | pssh -h <(grep -A1 dp15 ~/.ssh/config | grep -vE -- '#|--') ...
```

The above could be used to extract a list of IPs from my `~/.ssh/config` file. You can of course also use `printf` to generate dynamic content too:

```
$ cat .... | pssh -h <(printf "%s\n" srv0{0..9}) ....
```

For example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" srv0{0..9}
srv00
srv01
srv02
srv03
srv04
srv05
srv06
srv07
srv08
srv09
```

You can also use `seq` to generate formatted numbers sequences too!

#### References & similar tools to `pssh`

If you don't want to use `pssh` as I've done so above there are some other options available.

- [sshpt](https://code.google.com/p/sshpt/)
- [Ansible's authorized_key_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html)

Comment: `Ansible's authorized_key_module` seems not work for new machine. I have to ssh-copy-id xxx first, so I am looking for a way just use ansible add ssh-key for new machine, any idea?

Comment: @mithril - sounds like a bug, I'd ask on the Ansible forums about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with ssh-copy-id; it also adds a key every time you run it. If you are automating the process, your authorized_keys file quickly gets cluttered with duplicate keys. Here is a Python program that avoids both problems. It runs from the control server and puts the keys from one remote server into another remote server.

```
import subprocess
def Remote(cmd,IP):
    cmd = '''ssh root@%s '''%(IP)+cmd
    lines = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split())
    return '\n'.join(lines)
source = '123.456.78.90'
target = '239.234.654.123'
getkey = 'cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
getauth = 'cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys'
sourcekey = Remote(getkey, source).replace('\n','').strip()
authkeys = Remote(getauth, target).replace('\n','').strip()
if sourcekey not in authkeys: 
    keycmd=''' echo "%s" >>/root/.ssh/authorized_keys; 
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys '''%(sourcekey) # A compound shell statement
    print 'Installed key', Remote(keycmd,target)
else: print 'Does not need key'
```

Comment: my ssh-copy-id does that already:  WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system. Is this your attempt to steal keys? :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the parallel SSH tools (clusterssh, mssh, pssh) may be appropriate for you.

For instance, use cssh to log into all the machines and append the key yourself.

Comment: I already have a set of custom tools for doing everything I need, except for copying the key that is.

Comment: Exactly… so use this one tool for doing the one task that's missing. Though if this is going to be an ongoing thing, the script that MonkeeSage posted (adapted to read password from stdin and work on multiple servers) would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things that might fit the bill:

- Functionally the same question also asked at [How can I propagate my SSH pub key to a list of servers without having to type my password in over and over?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204985/how-can-i-propagate-my-ssh-pub-key-to-a-list-of-servers-without-having-to-type-m).
- There's a perl module, but it does not seem to be maintained much : https://github.com/Ruyk/pssh-copy-id

As mentioned in other answers, sshpass is likely the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I want to stress just how bad of an idea it is to:

1. Use a hard-coded password in your scripts
2. Use the same password on ALL of your servers...like...why!?
3. NOT use SSH public_key+password authentication if you insist on this
4. Save the password into a text file

Here is an implementation that is a bit more secure...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import getpass
import argparse

parser = argparse.argument_parser()
parser.add_argument('-l','--login', action='store', help='username')
parser.add_argument('-p','--port', action='store', default='22', help='port')
parser.add_argument('-L','--list', action='store', help='file list of IPs')
parser.add_argument('-i','--ip-address', action='store', nargs='+', metavar='host' help='ip or list of ips')

args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.login:
    print("You need a login, broski!")
    return 0

if args.list:
    ips = [i for i in open(args.list, 'r').readlines()]
    passwd = getpass.getpass('Password: ')

    for ip in ips:
        cmd = 'ssh-id-copy {0}@{1} -p {2}'.format(ip,args.port,passwd)            
        os.system('sshpass -p ' + passwd + ' ' + cmd)
        print("Key added: ", ip)   # prints if successful
        # ex: sshpass -p passwd ssh-id-copy login@1.1.1.1

elif args.host:
    ip = args.host
    cmd = 'ssh-id-copy {0}@{1} -p {2}'.format(ip,args.port,passwd)
    os.system('sshpass -p ' + passwd + ' ' + cmd)
    print("Key added: ", ip)   # prints if successful
else:
    print("No IP addresses were given to run script...")
    return 0
```

Comment: I wish people wouldn't give these lectures about security. We all have different security requirements. Imagine if every store in a mall made you go through the same procedure as airport security.

Comment: ⁺¹ to the prev. comment, indeed. E.g. I need it as part of CI for a Packer-created VM that only exists like 30 minutes to run tests and then gets destroyed.